# Renaming Ethernet devices in 16.04

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, network-bonding

After swapping CPU and mobo, I've had a lot of trouble getting networking running again. I deleted all my original bonding configs from `/etc/network/interfaces` and uninstalled NetworkManager.

It's now working with a dedicated line for the host and three unique lines for three different vlans on which my VMs are bridged.

`ip link`'s output still shows a bond0 interface. I was wondering whether you could help me locate where this is coming from.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

`/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
Host interface internes Netzwerk

auto rename2
iface rename2 inet static
address 192.168.2.100
gateway 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.2.100

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
auto rename4
iface rename4 inet manual
auto rename5
iface rename5 inet manual
```

Can anybody help me to locate and kill bond0?

Also I would really appreciate it if I could rename the interfaces. I tried it via entries in `/etc/systemd/network/`

As an example I did this for the rename2 nic:

```
[Match]
MACAddress=00:25:90:f3:9c:ea

[Link]
Name=mgmti0
```

Which doesn't work.

Thank you!

Edit: Managed to get rid of bond0 just now. A simple

```
ip link delete bond0
```

sufficed

Edit2: Well, one reboot later and an an interface has at the same time swapped names with another AND that one was renamed. Also bond0 is back again.

I think I'll pull a Windows on this machine and just reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

When the bonding module (kernel driver) loads, it creates by default a first interface with name bond0. You can just ignore this interface, it  does no harm.
You can also just delete it with

```
ip link delete bond0
```

However, next time it will be back again.
Indeed, you don't want the driver to create such an interface, because you can create any number of bond interfaces dynamically. When loading the module, you can pass an argument to the driver, not to create the interface, like

```
rmmod bonding ; modprobe bonding max_bonds=0
```

What you actually want to do is write a file `/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf` with

```
options bonding max_bonds=0
```